# How to test the stability assumption when using the CausalImpact package in R?

Tags: causalimpact

In the case of CausalImpact it is assumed that the relationship between covariates and treated time series, as established during the pre-period, remains stable throughout the post-period.

1. Why is it important that this assumption is fulfilled?
2. How can I check whether the assumption is fulfilled?

Answer (score 0):

1. Because `CausalImpact` uses a model fitted in the pre-period to predict the response in the post-period under the assumption that no intervention happened; the effect is calculated as the difference between actual observation and prediction. If the relationship between covariates and response does not remain stable, the prediction is not necessarily valid, and thus also the estimated effect.
2. This can not really be checked, it's an assumption that must be plausible by prior knowledge. However, by using a false intervention time that is earlier than the actual intervention, it is at least possible to check if the predicted response agrees with the actual observation in the original pre-period. This is not a real check for the assumption that refers to the original post-period, but at least a check for stability of the relationship in the pre-period.